# Floats, CSS, HTML - How can I do my positioning?

Tags: html, css, position

Previously I asked [How do I position buttons so they align horizontally with another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178672/how-do-i-position-buttons-so-they-align-horizontally-with-another-element). I need just a little more help with my CSS and HTML until I've completed it to where I like it.

I have everything but the buttons correctly positioned, so, any help is great! Thanks in advance.

Current Output:

[image: Current Output]

Current HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Aspen Development | Home</title>
    <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    </head>

<body> 
<div id="container">
  <div id="navMenu">
        <div id="header">
                <div id="brand"><a href="index.html">Aspen Development</a></div>
                <ul>
                  <li class="navButton">Home</li>
                  <li class="navButton">Pricing</li>
                  <li class="navButton">Contact Us</li>
                </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="content">
        <div id="contentContainer">
        <p><b>4.21.14</b> Welcome to Aspen Development.</p>
        <p><b>4.19.14</b> The website has been created!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  <div id="footer">
        <center><p style="margin-top: 17px; margin-bottom: 20px; font-size: 0.75em; ">Copyright &copy; 2014 Aspen Development | All Rights Reserved</p></center>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Current CSS:

```
    @charset "utf-8";

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, div {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#header ul {
    list-style-type: None;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

#header ul li {
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
}

body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: #FFF;
}

#navMenu, #footer {
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    border: 2px solid #E6E6E6;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#header {
    width: 1104px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: right;
}

#menu {
    float: right;
    padding: 12px 14px 16px;
    padding-top: 12px;
}

#brand {
    float: left;
}

#brand a {
    display: block;
    padding-top: 12px;
    padding-bottom: 16px;
    padding-right: 14px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 1.25em;
    text-align: justify;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.navButton {
    padding: 0 14px;
    margin-top: 50px;
    color: black;
    font-size: 0.75em;
}

#content {
    width: 100%;
}

#contentContainer {
    width: 1140px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#contentContainer p {
    margin: 20px;
}
```

Once again, thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Any hint of how you want them positioned?

Comment: It seems you assumed that everybody knows you asked [this previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23178672/1529630)

Comment: @ralph.m I'd just like the 'Home' 'Pricing' and 'Contact Us' buttons to be lowered just a smidge, so they're inline with the title 'Aspen Development'